# jquery ajax call - get returning value if dataType is simply a text (string)

Tags: jquery

I have the following code.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"blahblah.php",
    data: "{}",
    async: true,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function() {
       if(returning data from blahblah.php == true)
           window.location.href="http://www.blahblah.com/logout.php";
    }
});
```

1) No data need to be sent.

2) File "blahblah.php" does some processing and returns either true or false.

3) I want to get the response and If true redirect to another php page.

I do not know how to read the returning data of the function in the blahblah.php file!!

Thank you in advance.
George

Answer (score 17):

You have to pass a variable into the `success` call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"blahblah.php",
    data: "{}",
    async: true,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function( data ) {

        console.log(data);

    }
});
```

If the success method runs then you have successfully submitted the file and can redirect with a simple `document.location = "http://www.example.com/somewhere.php`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting dataType to `'json'`?
Also, you're not actually retrieving the response from the server on a successful callback.  Try this:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:"blahblah.php",
      data: "{}",
      async: true,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
         if(response == true) {
             window.location.href="http://www.blahblah.com/logout.php";
         }
      }
   });
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the response turns out that it is null.. Here are the contents of url:blahblah.php.


<?php  
include_once 'login/include/session.php'; 

if($session->logged_in )
{
 return true;
}else
 return true;


?>

Comment: how about same thing but revert dataType back to "text"?  because the most important piece you were missing is the response parameter in your success function.

Comment: Nop, none work.. I alert the response (alert("response is: "+response);) and I realized that when dataType="text" it prints nothing and when dataType="json" it prints out "null"! Help me plz!

Comment: The problem must be with the "blahblah.php" file. It is just 4 lines of code.. Is this file able to return a true of false value?

Comment: You can also try change the POST to a GET, especially because you're not posting any data to it.

Comment: You need to actually `echo 'True';` for anything to display on the PHP page, and for anything to be picked up in the response. `response` is `null` because that php has a blank output.

Answer (score 2):

If your success event is not call then you may be get **return data using complete event**

example

```
complete: function (data) {
    alert(data.responseText);
  },
```

using this you can get response data in this event