# Ajax call not appending to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My ajax call

```
$('#searchform').submit(function(event) {
  $.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "/list",
  dataType: "text",
  data: $("#searchform").serialize(),   
   beforeSend: function() {
              $(".se-pre-con").show();
           },
  success: function(data)
  {
    console.log(data);
    $("#testcontent").append(data);
    location.href="/test?"+$("#searchform").serialize();
  }

});
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This ajax call does not append the `data` to the `testcontent`div. I get the console log for data very well, but it just does not want to append. The div `#testcontent`is always empty.

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean div searchform is empty? Aren't you sending any data?

Comment: I meant the `testcontent` div

Comment: why are you "append" and one row after you redirect the page with location.href ?

Comment: @Cowgirl you're refreshing the page on success (assigning to `location.href`)? Why? That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @JaredSmith I actually want to re-direct to a new page where I want to append the success data

Comment: @Cowgirl just curious, but why ajax in that case? Submit your form to the other page and let it handle the default action...

Comment: @War10ck I am using ajax just and only just for that preloader, `beforeSend` so that I can give feedback while getting the `/list`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6316830/3254405

Comment: @Cowgirl use a button with a click handler that shows what you want to show with the `.pre-se-con` selector, then submits the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functionality works. If there is an issue, it's outside the scope of the source code that was given. I would suggest wrapping your redirect with a [setTimeout() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and letting the user know the will be redirect in X amount of seconds.

```js
/* Variable Defaults */
var dummyURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';

/* Bind Submit Event to Form */
$('#searchform').on('submit', function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: dummyURL,
    dataType: 'text',
    data: $('#searchform').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('.se-pre-con').show();
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#testcontent').append(data);
      console.log('Redirected To:', '/test?' + $('#searchform').serialize());
    }

  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.se-pre-con {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchform">
  <label>First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name">
  <br>
  <label>Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name">
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<p class="se-pre-con">
  Show Me Before Send!
</p>

<p id="testcontent"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are appending data to `#testcontent`, but there is one mistake here - you are refreshing the page on success by calling `location.href="/test?"+...` and the browser renders default view again.